# Recyclerview swipe up to refresh in android on API 21

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, refresh, android-support-library, swipe

I want "swipe up to refresh content" feature in recycler view (similar to `SwipeRefreshLayout`).

Currently I have a button which refreshes the view when tapped and I'd like to do the same using swiping up. The only problem is that `SwipeRefreshLayout` is available since API 22.

Is it possible to be done when using API 21?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout.
Add in your build.gradle `compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:x.x.x'`
where x.x.x is the last version of support library.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the class `android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout` which is inside the support library v4.

Add in you `build.gradle` the dependency:

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-core-ui:26.1.0'
```

Here you can find [all details](https://developer.android.com/training/swipe/add-swipe-interface.html) in the official doc.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout`. Though I found a problem with the support version and then I had to modify the `SwipeRefreshLayout` like this.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout;
import android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout;
import android.util.AttributeSet;

public class CustomSwipeRefreshLayout extends SwipeRefreshLayout implements AppBarLayout.OnOffsetChangedListener {
    private AppBarLayout appBarLayout;

    public CustomSwipeRefreshLayout(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public CustomSwipeRefreshLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onAttachedToWindow() {
        super.onAttachedToWindow();
        if (getContext() instanceof Activity) {
            appBarLayout = (AppBarLayout) ((Activity) getContext()).findViewById(R.id.appbar);
            if (appBarLayout != null)
                appBarLayout.addOnOffsetChangedListener(this);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDetachedFromWindow() {
        if (appBarLayout != null) {
            appBarLayout.removeOnOffsetChangedListener(this);
            appBarLayout = null;
        }
        super.onDetachedFromWindow();
    }

    @Override
    public void onOffsetChanged(AppBarLayout appBarLayout, int i) {
        this.setEnabled(i == 0);
    }
}
```

Now implement the custom `SwipeRefreshLayout` like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<your.package.name.CustomView.CustomSwipeRefreshLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/swipe_refresh_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/white">


    <!-- Your RecyclerView -->

</your.package.name.CustomView.CustomSwipeRefreshLayout>
```